# JMeter: Body & File content

Tags: jmeter

The WebAPI request has a POST method which expects Content body. I've tried to use both Parameters and Body options but I receive error responses - 'Invalid Request' with 400 Status code, etc.

JMeter request Sample Content Body:

```
{
    "ParamA": 111,
    "ParamB": "Char String",
    "ParamC": "VarType"
}
```

OR

```
{ "ParamA": 111, "ParamB": "Char String", "ParamC": "VarType"}
```

Listener Request:

- POST data:
  --8vpH3B6WcV4f1La46_wccVi4c25lrLJaGcN--

Listener Response:

- {"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"value":["An error
  has occurred."]}}

Any insight into viable options? Eventually, I'm planning on reading the Body string from a .csv file so I can parameterize the request. Reading from a .CSV file only reads the first line of the request body - for example: '{'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Ray

[HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCxnE.png)

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIQ4D.png)

Comment: Please share the request you are posting.

Comment: Naveen, I've added screenshots of the HTTP request and the request in the listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck in HTTP request the option:

- Use multipart/form data for POST

Also check your CSV does not contain some data that contains the CSV separator which is '\t' by default.

Ensure it doesn't by changing separator to '|' for example if you're sure your JSON will never contain it.

Comment: Hello, even without CSV, sending the following as the body content: Sample Content Body: { "ParamA": 111, "ParamB": "Char String", "ParamC": "VarType" } 
OR
{ "ParamA": 111, "ParamB": "Char String", "ParamC": "VarType"} fails with {"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"value":["An error has occurred."]}} and the listener request displays POST data:
--8vpH3B6WcV4f1La46_wccVi4c25lrLJaGcN--
rather than the actual content